# What is a "node" in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal node demystified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899956/drupal-node-demystified)

I am learning drupal now, but the node concept confuses me! Can anybody tell me what nodes are? Please provide example code.

Answer (score 1):

A node defines an individual piece of content within the Drupal system.  Any one given node may be:

1. A blog post
2. A generic web page (such as a "contact us" page)
3. An image uploaded using the image module
4. Or any one of many other types of content.

Nodes may have more than one version, so that you can track revisions to a piece of content over time.

Not everything is a node; for example, a commment on a blog post is not a node in and of itself.  Similarly, the administrative pages within Drupal are not nodes.  However, most of the pages you will create and manipulate within Drupal are nodes.